# Send message directly after AcceptBluetoothClient with 32feet

Tags: c#, 32feet

I would like to send a message directly after a device has connected to me.

So I start listening to incoming connections:

```
    public static void StartListen(BluetoothDeviceInfo foundDevice)
    {
        try
        {
            _listener = new BluetoothListener(_serviceClass);
            _listener.Start();

            _listener.BeginAcceptBluetoothClient(AcceptBluetoothClientCallback, _listener);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
```

Then I accept the the connection in an async way:

```
    private static void AcceptBluetoothClientCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        _client = _listener.AcceptBluetoothClient();
        var stream = _client.GetStream();


        var data = "hello";
        stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data), 0, data.Length);
        Console.WriteLine($"canRead: {stream.CanRead}");
        Console.WriteLine($"canWrite: {stream.CanWrite}");

        _client.Close();
    }
```

But `AcceptBluetoothClient` is a blocking call. So I don't get the client until the other part sends something. Is there a way to get the client/stream before this event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in the code, you are calling **AcceptBluetoothClient** twice, one of the calls is Asynchronous, and the other is Synchronous (blocking).
You mentioned that you are accepting the connection in an async way (and that's by calling **BeginAcceptBluetoothClient**), so you do not need to call **AcceptBluetoothClient** again inside the callback function **AcceptBluetoothClientCallback**, because at that moment you already accepted the new client. So, you just need to get the stream and continue the flow.

Comment: How does he call GetStream() if he doesn't have the _client?